# Extract some IPA from iPhone to USB Memory without jailbroken/download from App Store without iOS Device

Tags: macos, iphone, windows, unix, ios

How can I copy an IPA (iOS App Store Package) from my iPhone to a USB memory, using Linux, macOS, or Windows OS?

Alternatively, **How to download IPA directly to my Laptop from App Store without iOS Device?**

Answer (score 1):

Apple stopped supporting local backup of iOS apps in iTunes several versions ago. However there are apps available that will back up your iOS device *including the apps.*

I got [iMazing](https://imazing.com) in a Mac app bundle a while back and found it works as advertised and is well supported from the developer. It will back up your iOS device *including the apps on it* and store it locally on your Mac.

No relation to or interest in iMazing, just a happy customer. There are other apps that do similar things as well.